# Is there a way to compare a mongodb document with a mongodb query filter to see if they match

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to compare a mongodb document with a mongodb query filter to see if they match

I have a strange requirement, and now my approach is to create a temporary collection, then insert the documents and try to find in this collection, but this is too slow, I need a faster method to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB drivers do not implement MQL (MongoDB query language) evaluation.

Mongoid ODM does implement MQL evaluation for general-purpose operators. See https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#querying-embedded-associations and https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/tree/master/lib/mongoid/matcher.

Other ODMs may similarly implement MQL evaluation, but I don't know which ones actually do.